# How to get all valid WHEN clauses in a single case statement with mySQL?

Tags: mysql

In my database I have 3 separate database tables that store address information. The database table tells the address source. Please don't ask me to rework the database design as it's really not up to me; another team handles that.

Anyways, I am using a CASE WHEN statement to try and combine the address results for a single location from all 3 sources into a list. (as if they were pulled from a single table).

```
SELECT
    loc.ID,
    CASE 
         WHEN addr1.ID IS NOT NULL THEN addr1.ADDRESS 
         WHEN addr2.ID IS NOT NULL THEN addr2.ADDRESS 
         WHEN addr3.ID IS NOT NULL THEN addr3.ADDRESS 
    END as LOC_ADDRESS
FROM LOCATION loc
LEFT JOIN ADDRESS_1 addr1 ON loc.ID = addr1.LOCATION_ID
LEFT JOIN ADDRESS_2 addr2 ON loc.ID = addr2.LOCATION_ID
LEFT JOIN ADDRESS_3 addr3 ON loc.ID = addr3.LOCATION_ID;
```

I am using LEFT JOINs because it's optional for a Location to have an address in any/all of these sources. e.g. 1 Location may have an address each of these (or multiple) and another location may not have any addresses at all.

What I expected was that if a Location had an address in sources 1 and 3 those would both be returned. However, it seems that only the first valid WHEN condition is being returned.

How can I return all valid conditions?

**EDIT based on [Comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52708096/how-to-get-all-valid-when-clauses-in-a-single-case-statement-with-mysql/52708267#comment92342597_52708096):** I want it to return a list of addresses that matched. e.g. addr1 is valid and addr3 are valid then should look like loc.ID, addr1.ADDRESS on row 1 and loc.ID, addr3.ADDRESS on row 2. etc.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: what do you want it to return if there is not an address in the first or second database? What would the output look like if the first and third had values but second didn't?  Are you looking for one concatenated string of everything available

Comment: I want it to return a list of addresses that matched. e.g. addr1 is valid and addr3 are valid then should look like loc.ID, addr1.ADDRESS on row 1 and loc.ID, addr3.ADDRESS on row 2. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on OP's [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52708096/how-to-get-all-valid-when-clauses-in-a-single-case-statement-with-mysql#comment92342597_52708096), you need to just `Inner Join` with various address tables separately, and use [`UNION ALL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html).

Try the following instead:

```
SELECT
    loc.ID,
    addr1.ID AS LOC_ADDRESS
FROM LOCATION loc
JOIN ADDRESS_1 addr1 ON loc.ID = addr1.LOCATION_ID 

UNION ALL 

SELECT
    loc.ID,
    addr2.ID AS LOC_ADDRESS
FROM LOCATION loc
JOIN ADDRESS_2 addr2 ON loc.ID = addr2.LOCATION_ID 

UNION ALL 

SELECT
    loc.ID,
    addr3.ID AS LOC_ADDRESS
FROM LOCATION loc
JOIN ADDRESS_2 addr3 ON loc.ID = addr3.LOCATION_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want all the 3 addresses  if exist so `concat` function could help you

```
 SELECT
        loc.ID,
       concat( concat(addr1.ADDRESS,
              addr2.ADDRESS), 
             addr3.ADDRESS )
        as LOC_ADDRESS
    FROM LOCATION loc
    LEFT JOIN ADDRESS_1 addr1 ON loc.ID = addr1.LOCATION_ID
    LEFT JOIN ADDRESS_2 addr2 ON loc.ID = addr2.LOCATION_ID
    LEFT JOIN ADDRESS_3 addr3 ON loc.ID = addr3.LOCATION_ID;
```